# Is there a way to customize the tool tip of a custom object in the VS Debugger?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++

[Is there a way to customize the tool tip of a custom object in the VS Debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369192/is-there-a-way-to-customize-the-tool-tip-of-a-custom-object-in-the-vs-debugger/1725025#1725025)

anyway to do same for unmanaged c++? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had a look at `<VSInstallDir>\Common7\Packages\Debugger`?

Comment: Um, sorry. I thought I had that file's name copied, too. `<sheepish_grin>`